# Pin Authorization for Twitter using Javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth, twitter

I am a newbie here and having a hard time with this. I am using OAuth2.0 to integrate twitter(OOB method) with my app. I am writing it using Javascript/HTML5. I have done all the search but couldn't find a solution.

My problem is that Twitter gives me a pin number to complete authorization but I am not able to find a place where I can enter this pin to complete the process.

Should I go back to the app and have a text box and ask the user to enter the pin? If so, how do I go back to the app with having the pin screen? I don't know how to set an URL for my app to push the user go back to app?

Can anyone help plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you need to get the user to copy that pin into your application. your app will then use this pin [in the same way that the `oauth_verifier`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization) is used in the browser based oauth for twitter - ie you exchange it for the `oauth_token` and `token_secret` which you can then use to get use to get all user details.

btw i'm assuming when you say that you are writing an app, that you are not writing a browser app? if you are indeed writing a website that will be running in a browser then the pin based authentication is cumbersome and unnecessary. in this case you should use browser based oauth authentication. the difference is that rather than displaying a url in your app which a user then types into the browser address bar, you simply redirect the user to this twitter url and twitter redirects them back to your website if they provide a valid username and password.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am not writing a browser/web app. It's  a native app that runs without using browser. I wonder why an user should be redirected to another page/screen that is irrelevant to the app. So, the only possibility I see is that I have to request the user to by-heart the pin number and then ask him/her to come back to the app and enter it. This does not seem to be user-friendly. Twitter has to do something.

Comment: ah ok. yeah, in that case, the reason that your app has to display a url for the user to type in to a browser, then get them to copy the resulting pin back into your app is presumably because the device you use your app on does not have access to a web browser.